# DocuSign SOAP API - Envelope Size limit

Tags: docusignapi

The DocuSign SOAP api guide recommends that no one PDF file within the envelope exceed 25 mb in size, but is anyone aware of the overall envelope size limit? Our system has the potential to generate quite a few PDF files that in total could reach over 200 mb in size. Would the DocuSign api have trouble processing an envelope that large?

Answer (score 1):

The PDF size is limited to 25MB, the workflow specifications are usually tiny (it's JSON or XML).  The overall request size is 50MB assuming that certain PDFs can increase in size when they are base64 encoded.

You don't have to be limited by a request you can probably add documents to a draft envelope one by one.  There are also other ways to figure out how to send large files, but you would probably need to talk to an account manager and connect directly to our engineering.